# ios app, running accelerometer while the app is in the background

Tags: ios, iphone, background, accelerometer, foreground

I have an app using accelerometer. When a certain motion is detected, i am trying to make my iphone vibrate. While the app is in the foreground, and I conduct a certain motion, it vibrates. But it does not when the app is in the background.

I have a counter that detects this motion. When I execute this motion while in the background for three times, although it does not emit any vibration, after I transition back to foreground, the counter is increased by three. So I know the accelerometer is working. Or is putting the motions in a queue and executing it when the app comes back to foreground.

And I'm not making a rookie mistake by touching the phone's vibrate to off.

I'm quite not sure where to go from here. Is iphone inherently not capable of capturing and processing accelerometer data while in the background? Or is there something I'm not doing correctly?

Answer (score 1):

In iOS there are only a certain type of activities allowed in background. Here you can check them: [Background Modes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html).

I'm currently working in an app that uses sensors like the accelerometer and I get updates from it using the CoreLocation delegate method didUpdateLocation, since using the GPS to locate the device is one of the Apple allowed background modes. I hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Since this question was from some time ago, I have implemented the path you just suggested. But then, let me ask you a question. When your app uses GPS for background mode, the app shows a blue bar on the top. If your app needs gps, then ok. But if it doesnt, then don't you think asking gps permission seem invasive? My app does it. And it feels invasive. So i'm just curious what your thoughts are. Thank you.

Comment: My app need GPS. I agree with you, if you don't need GPS it feels invasive.